# Make Controll Mouse Zoom in QGraphicsView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsView` that can display an image, zoom in and zoom out . This is the code :

```
class MyQGraphicsView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(MyQGraphicsView, self).__init__ (parent)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
     # Zoom Factor
        zoomInFactor = 1.25
        zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor

    # Set Anchors
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)

    # Save the scene pos
        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

    # Zoom
        if event.delta() > 0:
            zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
        else:
            zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)

    # Get the new position
        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

    # Move scene to old position
        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())
```

What I want to do is restrict to zoom in or zoom out . The image size scaled the `qgraphicsview` size like this :

```
        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('pic.jpeg')
        w = self.graphicsView.width()
        h = self.graphicsView.height()
        scene.addPixmap(pixmap.scaled(QtCore.QSize(w,h)))
        self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
```

As you see image size is equal `qgraphicsview` size . In this position I don't want user zoom out image . Only if user zooms in image , can be zoom out but until the image size is equal `qgraphicsview` size . I didn't controll this . Can you suggest me a way ?